# Symfony 3.0 Openshift cannot find vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, openshift, symfony

Hello I made a small gear to Openshift with php 5.4 and Postgresql and I try to make my first Symfony app to work But somehow I get this weird logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/lib:/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/libs:/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/libraries:/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/src:/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor:/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/vendors:/var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/php/phplib/pear/pear/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/lib/openshift/56bf2dba0c1e663957000163/app-root/runtime/repo/app/autoload.php on line 9
```

Also I noticed that the installed composer is quite an old one. So when I login via ssh to my gear and I execute:

```
cd app-root/repo/
composer install
```

I get the following Errors:

```
Problem 1
- This package requires php >=5.5.9 but your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- Installation request for doctrine/cache v1.6.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[v1.6.0].
- doctrine/cache v1.6.0 requires php ~5.5|~7.0 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 3
- Installation request for doctrine/common v2.6.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[v2.6.1].
- doctrine/common v2.6.1 requires php ~5.5|~7.0 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 4
- Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.0.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.2].
- symfony/symfony v3.0.2 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 5
- doctrine/cache v1.6.0 requires php ~5.5|~7.0 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
- doctrine/orm v2.5.4 requires doctrine/cache ~1.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/cache[v1.6.0].
- Installation request for doctrine/orm v2.5.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.5.4].
```

Even if I change the Settings on my composer.json file:
http://pastebin.com/X5bYnPM4

Also from various tyutorials and lokking around I made these files:

.openshift/action_hooks/build:

```
# Symfony deploy
export COMPOSER_HOME="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.composer"
if [ ! -f "$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar" ]; then
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install
dir=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
else
php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar self-update
fi

cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
php `find -name build_bootstrap.php`
.openshift/action-hooks: http://pastebin.com/iVBmvY4X
```

Both of them are executable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade you PHP to 5.5.9

```
#composer.json
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
```

or install previous release of openshift

what is the full name of openshift package ?

Comment: I do not know I installed a free small Gear with php 5.4 and Postgresql. I think if by package tyou mean the plan is the free plan of the Openshift. I think maybe I should go to EC2 with a t2 micro instance where I can run easily an Ubuntu machine that has php 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

please check my starter project on [github](https://github.com/bigali/openshift-diy-php56-symfony3), it is a diy (do it yourself) app on openshift , with symfony3 and php5.6

Comment: You have Broken Link

Comment: sorry @DimitriosDesyllas , i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I should make a custom catridge in order to run php 5.5 or later.